# Problem when run imported files in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, import

I use `TexStudio` with a nested structure, in other words I have many files in many folders to help keep things tidy. The problem happens when I have to import another document.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{float, newfloat}
    \usepackage{svg}
    \usepackage{import}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{amsmath, mathrsfs, amsfonts, amsbsy, amsthm}
    \usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
    \usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{setspace}
        \onehalfspacing
    
    % Definition of some commands
    % FONTS
        \newcommand{\definiz}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\symdef}[1]{\ensuremath{\pmb{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\unit}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
        \newcommand{\important}[1]{\textit{#1}}
        \newcommand{\strangeword}[1]{\textit{#1}}
    
    % WORDS
        \newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{\topsep}{\topsep}{\normalfont}{0pt}{\bfseries}{:}{0.5em}{}
        \theoremstyle{mystyle}
        \newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
        \newtheorem*{example}{Example}
        \newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
        
    % MATH SYMBOL
        \newcommand{\eto}{\ensuremath{\, \mathrm{e}}}
        \newcommand{\tento}[1]{\ensuremath{ \times 10^{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\Real}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
        
    \begin{document}
        % Importing the title and the introduction =========================================================================
        \import{./Titlepage/}{titlepage}
        \ \thispagestyle{empty}
        \clearpage
        
        \import{./Titlepage/}{introduction}
        \ \clearpage
        
        % Importing the various chapters ==============================================================
        \import{./Chapter 1/}{basics}
        
        
    \end{document}
```

Usually I can make the program 'run' from imported files (by pressing `F5`) but when creating a new file to import I can no longer do that. And the program  gives me the error:

> Missing \begin{document}. \subsection*

The program works fine if I make the script run from the main.tex file and from every other file that I've created before. What can I do?

I'll add some screenshots to explain better:
[image: This is what happen when I run the program from the main file]
[image: Instead this is what happen when I run the program from the imported file]

The first shows what happens when I run the program from the main file, and the second instead what happen when I run the program from the imported file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeXstudio, but I would instead `\import` rather use `include` command. Both should be independent from used editor (both are LaTeX commands).

Answer (score 1):

You should define a master document and pay attention while creating new files with `Ctrl + Click` in TeXstudio. From your screenshots, it seems you don't use the `Structure` at the left side, so I'm not sure where your files are stored.

I created a new file within the command `import` and it was created in the same folder as `document.tex`. Compiling will return an error: `File` section1/input_file_from_folder.tex' not found. \import{section1/}{input_file_from_folder}` .

[image]

Moving it inside the folder `section1`, will work if you compile (`F5`) from `document.tex`, but not from the imported file.

[image]

Defining `document.tex` as master document (`explicit root`) solves the issue.

[image]

Please, notice that a symbol at the left side of `document.tex` has added. This symbol means that document is the root. It will always be present at the top.

[image]

*Notes*:

1. I'm using TeXstudio version 3.1.2, but this feature is older than this version and works at the newer versions.
2. Documents on the left panel named `Structure` change colors and show when TeXstudio recognizes/finds them and when not, but it doesn't mean the compilation process will or will not work. It should be so, but this feature behaves a little bit strange.
3. Setting the master document works with `input`s, `include`s and (sub)`import`s.

Suggestions to read:

- [input vs include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)
- [Management in a large project](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project)

---

*Edit*: `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
\import{section1/}{input_file_from_folder}
\end{document}
```